# Deleting text files based on date through SQL Server T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, tsql

I need to delete .txt files in a particular directory based on date.  Can I do this through T-SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is an article](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/delete-file-from-sql-server-xp-cmdshell-ole-automation-procedures.aspx) with instructions for:

- How to delete a file using xp_cmdshell extended procedure
- How to delete a file using OLE Automation Procedures